# How to classify this surface

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, surfaces, knot-theory

[image]

I know that it should be either a sphere, torus, Klein bottle, real projective plane, or a connect sum of any combination of these, but I don't know the steps in identifying what kind of surface this is.

I know there are $2$ boundary components, but I don't know how many vertices or edges there are, or how many Seifert discs. There's an even number of half-twists, so this surface is orientable.

Comment: Why do you think it is one of those? It isn't a compact 2-manifold. It is a compact 2-manifold with boundary, which includes things like cylinders and Möbius strips.

Comment: Generally, the best a approach is via cutting, until you get to a simply-connected surface.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: This looks to me like something someone would see if they were studying handlebody diagrams in the context of surfaces. I suspect that what's intended is to take this picture and then glue on discs to the two boundary circles. If that's the case, then I would argue that the easiest way is to do a single handleslide to 'untangle' and then recognize it as the connected sum of two known manifolds.

Comment: Seifert's algorithm?

Comment: You can compute the Euler characteristic of the surface's core graph (I think it is 2), which will be the same as the Euler characteristic of the surface (EC is a homotopy invariant), then investigate how removing discs from closed orientable surfaces changes Euler characteristic.  As Mike Miller suggests, if you attach a disk along each boundary component, you'll get a closed surface and you're done by the classification of surfaces.

Comment: @Charlie What is a "core graph"?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is standard terminology, but I mean a simplicial 1-complex in the interior of your surface onto which your surface deformation retracts.  In your picture, put a vertex wherever 2 bands come together and draw edges in the bands between the vertices.

Comment: @Charlie Do I need to put a vertex wherever there is a twist in the bands as well?

Comment: Nope, the twists don't matter for the core graph (I think some refer to it as the spine of the surface).  Also, 2 isn't the Euler characteristic, I made a mistake.

Comment: @Charlie: Careful: this is not an orientable surface! Other than that, I agree with what you said.

Comment: @Charlie Here is the picture I drew. I'm not sure what constitutes as a "band" though: http://i.imgur.com/8IkrknK.png So I get $6$ vertices, $9$ edges, and 0 faces, so I get an Euler characteristic of $-3$

Comment: @MikeMiller I thought because there's an even number of half-twists (two of them in the picture), then it is orientable

Comment: Any number of half-twists means your surface is non-orientable. You can't "cancel them out", they're there for life.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Thanks, you're absolutely right! After I (correctly) computed the EC I realized it was nonorientable...

Comment: @morphic your spine and EC are right.  As Mike Miller said, you have a little more work to do since the surface is non-orientable.

Comment: @MikeMiller On the 3rd to last line on the bottom of page $3$ here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0143.pdf it says that when the number of half-twists are even, the surface is orientable

Comment: It means if you have an even number of half-twists on a single band. If you have any band with an odd number of half-twists you're out of luck.

Comment: Ok, since there're 2 boundary components, this surface is a connect sum of 2 surfaces. The Euler char. is $\chi(F_1 \# F_2) = \chi(F_1) + \chi(F_2) - 2$, so $-3 = \chi(F_1) + \chi(F_2) - 2 \implies \chi(F_1) + \chi(F_2) = -1$. So $F_1$ and $F_2$ are a combo of two nonorientable surfaces, or one of them orientable and the other not. The only thing I can think of is the Klein bottle since it's a connect sum of two $\Bbb RP^2$, and the other combos I'm thinking of either lead to a connected sum of $3$ surfaces (such as $T^2 \# \Bbb RP^2 = \Bbb RP^2 \# \Bbb RP^2 \# \Bbb RP^2$) or something else

Comment: But the Euler characteristic of the Klein bottle is not $-1$

Answer (score 2):

With a couple of moves, if you know how to recognize it you can see that it is a twice-punctured $T^2\mathop{\#}\mathbb{R}P^2$.  If you do not know how to recognize it, I have draw some pictures that might convince you.

[image: Altering the original diagram to see its decomposition]

Comment: +1, but minor quibble. $S^2\setminus\{x_1,x_2\}$ is an open surface (no boundary) whereas the original surface had two boundary components.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip They were open points of course :-)  (changed it)

Comment: ha!$\phantom{.}$